# MalformedURLException:?

Tags: java, android, json, exception

We are using Async task for service call this service is by 3rd party which i need to call and get json data then according i need to move for other thing so for that I used this code.

```
private class FetchJsonData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast


            URL url = new URL("android-app://ir.com.irremote.ir.com.irremote.activity/http/" + "api.abc.com/TVlistings/v9/listings/services/postalcode/37215/info?locale=en-US&countrycode=US&format=json&apikey=abc");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            return forecastJsonStr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.i("json", "" + s);
    }
}
```

After that i excute on onCreate() but it gives me some exception i don't know why it's coming .i put log here please see this:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: ir.dumadu.com.irremote, PID: 20759
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {ir.dumadu.com.irremote/ir.dumadu.com.irremote.ir.dumadu.com.irremote.activity.ChoseTransmitter}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppIndex: The URI host must match the package name and follow the format (android-app:////[host_path]). Provided URI: android-app://ir.dumadu.com.irremote.ir.dumadu.com.irremote.activity/http/host/path
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:4679)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:211)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppIndex: The URI host must match the package name and follow the format (android-app:////[host_path]). Provided URI: android-app://ir.dumadu.com.irremote.ir.dumadu.com.irremote.activity/http/host/path
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjt.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.end(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at ir.dumadu.com.irremote.ir.dumadu.com.irremote.activity.ChoseTransmitter.onStop(ChoseTransmitter.java:169)
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1305)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6777)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:4676)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:211) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1934) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> Here what ever i am using this url i.e. my backend url. this url is gave us some service provider.when i hit this url in web browser then it's gave me json formatted data.but when i called through our mobile app it's give above log.if you people find any mistakes in that or i need to do some other way you reply me definitely.
>   thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to add valid url as string eg URL url = new URL("http://fb.com/");

Comment: now i got the solution: 1st we need to create string variable to particular url. like. String urlStr = "http://whatever.com"; URL url = new URL(urlStr);then it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class FetchJsonData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at


            String urls="http://" + "api.abc.com/TVlistings/v9/listings/services/postalcode/37215/info?locale=en-US&countrycode=US&format=json&apikey=abc";
            URL url = new URL(urls);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
           //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            return forecastJsonStr;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.i("json", "" + s);
    }
}
```

> Now it's work.

Comment: While it may work, its always nice to include in the description what changes you made and how they'd fix the issues so the OP and others may get a clearer picture. Also, when including code, its mostly sufficient to only include the relevant lines in the answer.

Comment: Cool...I'd suggest include the answer description with the answer only.

Comment: thank you for suggesting me.i remembered in next time.

Comment: @user6615010 you don't need to remember, you can edit you questions / answers always.